# Please help me to get Force.com Connector for SAP R/3?

Tags: integration

Please help me to get Force.com Connect for SAP R/3 ? I didnt find a link for this salesforce app that deploys the connector in my SFDC developer edition? Can someone help on this?

Thanks,
Baskaran

Comment: I believe you need to raise a case with Salesforce support asking them to enable this connector for you. Please see [this](https://login.salesforce.com/?startURL=https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00D30000000XsfGEAS/HTAuthProvider?startURL=/apex/HTDoor&site=https://help.salesforce.com) link for how to raise a support case.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately there is no option to submit a case. When i click "Submit Case" button there is no option to submit a case. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Are you following the steps listed at : http://blogs.salesforcefoundation.org/2013/08/18/how-to-log-a-technical-support-ticket-with-salesforce-com/ - if so, is this a sandbox - you can't open a case from a sandbox, you have to use the associated production org.

Comment: @BobBuzzard Thanks for the response. I am using free developer edition and dont have sandbox or prod org. How can i resolve this?

Comment: I would tweet to @salesforce telling them of the problem - they usually pick up this stuff pretty quickly.

Comment: Skyvva.com has a connector for Salesforce and SAP

Comment: @BaskaranS Hi Baskaran, could you please advise if you need a connector even if SAP PI is in place ?